# Vertica - Remove command execution

Tags: vertica, vsql

I have a query sequence in Vertica below:

```
drop table [table_name]; 
create [table_name] as select ...;  
drop table [table_name];
create [table_name] as select ...;  
select ...;
```

My resulting file looks like

```
DROP TABLE  
CREATE TABLE
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
column1 | column2 | column3 |
```

Does Vertica have a configuration parameter that can eliminate the 'DROP' and 'CREATE' table and retains only the SELECT output?

Comment: You are probably looking for the `-q` (quiet) option: https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/vsql/CommandLineOptions.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried that a while a go it didn't work, moved it in another place in the command line suddenly it worked. Thanks for this.